# Changing FXML element from outside the Controller with reference - NullPointerException

Tags: javafx, reference, controller, fxml

I want to change the text of an FXML element from outside the Controller class by using a reference I create in main function but I get a NullPointerException.

**Class Controller:**

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    public ComboBox<String> comboBoxSelectPort;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        Language l = new Language(); 
        l.setLanguage();

        comboBox.setPromptText("New Text");   // This works!
    }
}
```

**Class Language:**

```
public class Language {

    private Controller c = Main.controller;

    public void setLanguage(){

        c.comboBox.setPromptText("New Text");   // This is NOT working!
    }
}
```

**UPDATE 1:**

Class Main:

```
public class Main extends Application {

    public static Stage stage;
    public static Controller controller;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Scene.fxml"));
        Parent root = (Parent) loader.load();
        controller = (Controller) loader.getController();
        System.out.println(controller);           // Works!
        ....
```

But in Controller or Language class

```
System.out.println(Main.controller);     // Output: Null
```

**UPDATE 2:**

The problem seems to be, that the Controller is created in Main befor the reference is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the controller reference to the `Language` instance:

```
public class Language {

    private final Controller c ;

    public Language(Controller controller) {
        this.c = controller ;
    }

    public void setLanguage(){

        c.comboBox.setPromptText("New Text");   // This is NOT working!
    }
}
```

and then

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    public ComboBox<String> comboBoxSelectPort;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

        Language l = new Language(this); 
        l.setLanguage();

        comboBox.setPromptText("New Text");   // This works!
    }
}
```